# Unable to install metis for python

Tags: python, metis

I ran into a problem installing metis for python. I have been using the following guide:
https://metis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
there is a step called make "config shared = 1" but I am not sure where this goes or where to type it.
please help

Comment: Read about the `make` command in `linux` systems, if you are not familiar with that. That command has to be run in a terminal (apparently after you download the necessary METIS files).